# How to pass request response objects using jsp and servlets when i will click a particular button

Tags: jsp

I am creating a dashboard , in dashboard I am getting req response object, but when I will click on a link to get other jsp page then in other jsp page I am not able to get req resp object please tell me the patten to get request object in other jsp page when I will click on a link. 
                `

about

// atten() function of javascript is not working 
                        // if i am using forward then it autometically forward the page without showing current page
                        //in this page getAttribute and setAttribute is working

```
                    <a  id ="attendance" href="attendance" onclick="atten()" > Attendance</a> 

                    <%String uname = (String)request.getAttribute("uname");
                    out.print(uname);
                    %>

                    <%request.getRequestDispatcher("AttendanceServlet").forward(request, response);

                    %>

                    please tell what should i write here so that when i will click on a link then it will transfer
                     the current page request and response to other page jsp

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Leave</a>
                </li>
                <!-- <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li> -->strong text][1]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send the data from a jsp to other jsp using `session`

A.jsp

```
  <% String userid="Nick";%>
    <form action="B.jsp" method="post">
    <%
    session.setAttribute("userId", userid);
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

B.jsp

```
 <%String userid = session.getAttribute("userId").toString(); %>
    Hello<%=userid%>
```

### OR

if you are looking for forwarding whole request/response you need to create a servlet

[heres](https://github.com/nikhilz/jsp-Servlet-Login) a simple example of *jsp-servlet-jsp*